# Logo Centered in Menu

Tags: css, bulma

I'm creating a menu using Bulma CSS. I have the following logo:

[image]

And I would like to use it much like the Atlantic did, in the center of the page. However, I'm not sure how; I've tried `margin-auto:0`, but that didn't work out. I also tried messing with the margins, and flexbox and inline-block, but to no avail. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Here is the page thus far (on Codepen): https://codepen.io/Refath/full/ZEQzOQX

Additional Information: The Navbar is currently using one of Bulma's Components, as follows in the snippet below:

```
     <nav class="navbar" role="navigation" aria-label="main navigation">
<form id="demo-2">
    <input type="search" placeholder="Search">
</form>
  <div id="navbarBasicExample" class="navbar-menu">
    <div class="navbar-start">
      <a class="navbar-item">
        Math
      </a>

      <a class="navbar-item">
        Science
      </a>
      <a class="navbar-item">
        Politics
      </a>

      <a class="navbar-item">
        Economics
      </a>

      <a class="navbar-item">
        Education
      </a>

      <a class="navbar-item">
        Literature
      </a>

      <div class="navbar-item has-dropdown is-hoverable">
        <a class="navbar-link">
          More
        </a>

        <div class="navbar-dropdown">
          <a class="navbar-item">
            About
          </a>
          <a class="navbar-item">
            Jobs
          </a>
          <a class="navbar-item">
            Contact
          </a>
          <hr class="navbar-divider">
          <a class="navbar-item">
            Report an issue
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="navbar-end">
      <div class="navbar-item">
        <div class="buttons">
          <a class="button is-primary">
            <strong>Sign up</strong>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: I think you mean `margin: auto`. Not `margin-auto:0`.

Comment: Thanks; Quickly fixed

Answer (score 0):

Use `margin: 0 auto;` or `margin: auto;`

It will work like this,

`margin: auto;` will be margin automatic from all four sides, and in case of

`margin: 0 auto;`. it will be 0 from top and bottom and auto from left and right.

Comment: Hi, I've just tried it but it messed up my formatting. Would you mind showing me the working example?

Comment: ok, I am giving you working example, just a small question, as your menu items are too much and you want your logo exactly center, so is it ok for you to move some of your menu items to more list?

Comment: OK, I moved some of them to the more list

Comment: Can you please check now?

Comment: I have created 2 versions for you, in both version I have changed the HTML structure, if you find any problem related to that, feel free to ask 
https://codepen.io/atulraj89/pen/WNreoem in this, I have used transform and logo is exactly center. and in this one https://codepen.io/atulraj89/pen/BajBQaq , its not center, it will depend on the items in your menu

Comment: Thank you; I will take a look and adjust them as neccesary.

Comment: if this will help you then, dont forget to up-vote and I am changing the answer accordingly, so Mark it as right answer, only if it helps

Comment: and one more thing, I am not aware of your requirements, but as per my knowledge its not ideal to use bulma with Bootstrap. they are alternatives to each other.